# Having a sprite image inside a button with text

Tags: html, css, button, href, sprite

I'm trying to create a button and here is the [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ts5x1xqo) so far.

Right now I can't figure out how I can position the sprite image so that only the black icon is visible.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is what I want to achieve with the button:

No hover:

[image: Language-button-no-hover]

Hover:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

HTML:

```
<a class="top-language" href="#" alt="Choose your language">Language</a>
```

CSS:

```
.top-language {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 35px;
  background: url("http://imageshack.com/a/img853/7081/1u5z.png") no-repeat 0 0;
}


 .top-language:hover {
  background: url("http://imageshack.com/a/img853/7081/1u5z.png") no-repeat 0 -22;   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z24f8/4/)

```
.top-language {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    width: 100px;
    color: #202020;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 13px;  
    width: 80px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: right;
    text-decoration: none;        
    background: url("http://imageshack.com/a/img853/7081/1u5z.png") no-repeat top left ;
    }


.top-language:hover {
    background-position: bottom left;
    color: #d13030;  
    }
```

Comment: I changed a bit, take a look [DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/mf2cpoaq). The only thing i need to know now is how I can add some space to the grey border so it doesn't stick to the text and the icon

Comment: Adding   padding-right: 10px; will fix the border on the right. The icon itself will need padding around it to prevent the border from touching it.

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the jsfiddle in my main post to reflect the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

a. reduce the height of the button;

b. increase the vertical gap between the two sprites in the image itself;

c. background: url(...) no-repeat 0 2px; adjust the value to push out the red icon

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-language {
  display: block;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background: url('http://imageshack.com/a/img853/7081/1u5z.png') bottom;
  text-indent: -99999px;
}


.top-language:hover {
  background-position: 0 0;  
}
```

Comment: In the demo only the icon is visible, how can i add text and border to it so it looks more like the images i posted?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide image display position as follows:

```
display:inline-block
```